# Why is my date of week printing one day behind today?

Tags: apex

having some date issues. Here is my code snippet (enjoy the name of my method) >>

```
public class DateLogicClass {

    public static void iHopeThisWorks() {
        //Declaring all my variables
        Date startDate;
        Date endDate;
        Date materialsDueDate;
        Date internalDueDate;
        Boolean materialsDue2Weeks = True;

        //System.debug('What is the date here?, nothing?' + startDate);

        startDate = date.today();
        endDate   = date.today();
        DateTime endDateDT = endDate;
        String dayOfWeekString = endDateDT.format('EEEE');


        System.debug('What is the date here? Thursday? ' + dayOfWeekString);

        switch on dayofWeekString {
            when 'Monday'  {
                System.debug('What is the date here? ' + dayOfWeekString);
                materialsDueDate = startDate - 5;
                System.debug('What is the date here?' + materialsDueDate);
            }
            when 'Tuesday' {
                System.debug('This line won\'t print' + dayOfWeekString);
            }
            when 'Wednesday' {}
            when 'Thursday' {}
            when 'Friday' {}
            when 'Saturday' {}
            when 'Sunday' {}
            when null {}

        }

     }

 }
```

I've put in today's date and it's Thursday 7:00P EST (I'm in Washington, DC) but when I print to the debug log, I get this:
[image]

Which is a full day behind. I've checked my locale settings and time settings in my org, they are set to English and Eastern time. So I'm sort of confused what I'm doing work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use type coercion, as it can have unpredictable results. Basically, these two lines are tripping you up:

```
Date endDate = Date.today();
Datetime endDateDT = endDate;
```

You should instead use `Datetime.newInstance` with a specific `Time` instance:

```
Datetime endTime = Datetime.newInstance(endDate, Time.newInstance(12, 0, 0, 0));
```